# Probability of winning the thunderball

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The Thunderball is where you have to choose five numbers from $\{1, . . . , 34\}$ and one from $\{1, . . . , 15\}$. I tried to find the probability of winning the Thunderball by first finding ${{34}\choose{5}}+{{15}\choose{1}}$ which is $278271$. And then that would mean that the chances of winning are $1$ in $278271$ which I know is not right since the correct answer is $1$ in $8,060,598$. I'm not exactly sure what else I can do.

Comment: multiplication?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yeah I tried multiplying the two combinations together but I still didn't get the right answer (I got $4173840$).

Comment: The numbers go from 1 to 39, and the thunderball goes from 1 to 14 https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/games/thunderball/about-thunderball